# select min value in same row in sql

Tags: sql

I want to select min value of dates in same row of different columns.

e.g.

```
column1       column2     column3
2017-01-26  2017-01-28  2017-01-27
```

in above three columns i would like to select min date i.e. result of select should be `2017-01-26`

Comment: Please add tag with database type + version

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Most databases support `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(column1, column2, column3) as min_column,
       greatest(column1, column2, column3) as max_column
```

In any database, you can use ANSI standard `case` for the logic:

```
select (case when column1 >= column2 and column1 >= column3 then column1
             when column2 >= column3 then column2
             else column3
        end) as max_column
```

(And then similar logic for the min.)

Answer (score 2):

If using SQL Server, you can use this approach:

```
SELECT (SELECT MIN(columnX) FROM (VALUES(column1), (column2), (column3)) x(columnX))
FROM ...
```